# prevent solr phrase query from being stemmed or stripped of stopwords

Tags: solr, match, phrase

I'm trying to check if this feature is even possible to implement with Solr.

I have a text field defined and on the query analyzer I've defined among others a **StopFilterFactory** and a **PorterStemFilterFactory**.

I use **edsimax** as the request handler.

under my current implementation, if i search for:
q = **"this is a phrasing query" this is not phrasing**

the lucene query will be: (excuse me for the pseudo syntax )
**text:"this ? ? phras query" | text: this | text:phras**

where what i would like to get is:
**text:"this is a phrasing query" | text: this | text:phras**

In other words i would like to set the behavior of wrapping a phrase with quotes to be:
a document will only match if the entire phrase without any tokenizing will appear in it.

I understand it maybe possible by defining an additional field which will not undergo any processing and increasing it's boost on the edismax configuration.

but this will return matches for documents which don't include the exact phrase.

Can this be implemented on Solr?
How?

Comment: unless you're willing to tinker with the edismax code to treat phrase queries in a special manner, i don't think you'll get the behavior you want . May i ask why the stop word removal bothers you ?

Comment: the main feedback i get on our search engine is that searching with quotation marks returns irrelevant results. Especially when searching for error codes that include stopwords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about matching different parts of the query against separate fields? Either through a `fq` to filter against `text_exact` or through regular search syntax for scoring as well: `text_exact:"this is a phrasing query" this is not phrasing` where the last terms should be searched against the default search field or `qf` iirc.

Comment: I guess that this is a valid option. I was hoping to get some sort of configuration or extension reference but i guess this could be made to work